# How to make Unit Test For function Use Spinner selected position?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have Function Thats Test ItemSelectedPosition For Spinner And i want to make Unit Test 
This is example for function i want to test

```
public boolean isGenderValid() {
    return (genderSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() != 0);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do so by creating a mock of the Spinner class and inject that into the class you want to test.

For example:

```
public class SpinnerStub extends Spinner {
     public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
          return 1;
     }
}
```

Then you create a `SpinnerStub` in your Test and set it as the `genderSpinner` of the class you want to test.
I'm not familiar with android controls, but I assume there's a method to set the selected item as well. You could also override that one in the Stub and use it to have `getSelectedItemPosition()` return the value you have set before.

The actual unit test could look like this:

```
@Test
public void whenSelectionIsValid_isGenderValidShouldReturnTrue() {
      YourClass sut = new YourClass();
      SpinnerStub spinnerStub = new SpinnerStub();
      sut.setSpinner(spinnerStub);

      assertTrue(sut.isGenderValid());
}
```